# Custom polygon style: outline with rectangular markers

Tags: qgis, polygon, style

I try to create a custom style in QGIS for some of my polygons I'm using. The border of the polygons should look like this:

[image: Polygon Style]

I tried to create two dashed lines (with a offset for one and some spacing for both) to create two parallel lines. But at this point I already have some trouble finding the right values. Also, I have no idea to create the vertical lines. Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go: [link to qgis-style](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cki36rhytwjjpwe/20180226_halfsquared_ploygon_border.qml?dl=0)

You might want to change some stuff. Real customization would be building your own svg and using that one.

Short addon on how to create custom borders: Property of layer -> style -> single symbol -> change layer type to marking line. Then choose a proper symbol from the presets, or build your own svg and use that one (maybe you have to, if you really need the serifs).

Comment: Since the objective of stack exchange it to share knowledge, I would prefer to see an explanation of how you were able to do the style. Even if you provide it in the end.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto I'll provide this when I come around to changing QGIS to english and doing all the screenshots.